# About the react router link problem state field name problem

Tags: javascript, react-router

Here is my code:

```
<Link 
  state={{"contact":contact}}
  to="/admin/contact/Edit"
  >
  <Button variant="warning"><Pencil/></Button>
</Link>
```

In the destination, I can get the contact object by the following coding:

```
let data = useLocation();
console.log(data.state.contact);
```

I want the field name to be dynamic.
So, I have tried the following coding, unfortunately in the destination, I cannot get the contact object.

```
let fieldName="contact"; 
 return(
  <Link 
      state={{ fieldName:contact}}
      to="/admin/contact/Edit"
    >
    <Button variant="warning"><Pencil/></Button>
  </Link>
 );
```

How can I make it work?

Comment: Can you please specify your react-router-dom library version?

Comment: I am using 6.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean the property key is dynamic then the code would look something more like the following:

```
<Link 
  state={{ [fieldName]: contact }}
  to="/admin/contact/Edit"
>
  <Button variant="warning"><Pencil/></Button>
</Link>
```

`fieldName` is a dynamic key and would be used in the same way in the receiving component.

```
const { state } = useLocation();

const value = state[fieldName];
```